# Does any MOF implementation exist in C++?

Tags: c++, uml, xmi

Is there any alternative to JMI for C++? Thanks for the links or suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EMF4CPP](http://catedrasaes.inf.um.es/trac/wiki/EMF4CPP) has just now been published. It is basically an implementation of Ecore in C++ (and Ecore is basically an adaptation of the Essential MOF OMG standard). Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I've found this library so far: [OMF](http://www.sdml.info/projects/omf/). Looks like it's not maintained since 2004, and doesn't support MOF 2.0, only MOF 1.4… Anyone has experience with it?